# DJANGO - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' when trying to acess a file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django, file-not-found

I'm accessing a function from a script that basically reads a JSON file and returns some value.

- `main/randomgenerator/generatorran.py`

```
def getName():
    with open('names.json','r') as names:
             ....
```

- The function works normally when executing it manually (`python generatorran.py`)

I'm currently importing that function and calling it when creating a model.

- `main/models.py`

```
from main.randomgenerator import generatorran


class myModel:
    ...
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=generatorran.getName())
```

- When applying migrations it throws an error

  `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' when trying to acess a file`

**The same happens when I move the function inside of the models.py**

Is there another way to read data from external files,am I missing something?

Comment: try using absolute path of `names.json` instead of relative path.

Comment: absolute path does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django cannot find the file because the current working directory is somewhere else

to check this out add this in your python file

```
print os.getcwd()
```

as Vishal Singh said in his comment use an absolute path instead of the relative one